# What's the exact cause of the class cast exception in the next code?

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object[]> list = getIt();

//        unsuccessful iteration, throws ClassCastException
        for (Object id : list) {
            System.out.println(id);
        }

//        successful iteration  
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }

    private static List<Object[]> getIt() {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(1L);
        return list;
    }
}
```

I understand at a rough estimate what happens(the iterator generated by the compiler contains an explicit cast), but would like some good answers, thanks.

Comment: It's just a feature of the language. What else are you looking for then?

Comment: It compiles and executes without problem on Eclipse. Show us the stacktrace, and the version of Java you're using.

Comment: I don't get any exceptions running your code.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; at the for each loop

Comment: Whether you get an exception or not, it kind of looks wrong to have an `Object[]` in any code.

Comment: I don't speak hear about best practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think it's because under the cover the java compiler generates smth like this :

```
Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println((Object[])iterator.next());
        }
```

and the explicit cast gives the error.
Generally, it's the problem of mixing generics with raw types, but, as I already said, I don't speak here about best practices.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this with Java 7 I don't get a ClassCastException, nor would I expect it to as the object is cast as `Object` in main();